# Should I contribute to a (kind of) abandoned project, or continue my own?

Tags: github

*I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask this question. This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273156/how-should-i-contribute-to-a-mostly-abandoned-github-project).*

So a few months ago I discovered project X on Github. Some info on project X:

- X has a lot of stars on Github (~3k)
- X has not been actively maintained for almost a year
- X has a new version being developed seperately from X(1), X2, which will be fundamentally different from X(1) - but the idea stays the same

I then created project Y, which is a spin-off of X. Some info on project Y:

- Y has a similar front-end to X, but a completely different back-end
- Y is written in the same language as X, the file architecture is similar
- Y has about 1/20 of the stars on Github that project X has
- Y borrowed very small parts of code from X, attribution was provided
- Y has *way, way more* functionality than project X
- The idea behind X and Y is the same

Recently, the owner of contributor X contacted me. He gave me the idea that instead of contuining project Y, I should start to contribute to X and continue from there - because even if X2 will be released, a lot of users will still use X1. He will give me callobrater persmission if I want to continue X.

My problem is: I have put *a lot* of effort in my project Y. It's something i'm proud of. However, Y is not getting a lot of attention. [I also want to include project Y on my resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24128/should-i-include-my-github-page-on-my-resume). If I continue to work on X, then I will basically update X to be Y, so i'd delete Y. That will mean I have no 'own' project I could put on my resume.

The only thing I could think of is asking the owner of X to [transfer the repo](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/) to my account, as I will be the only one maintaining it. But I doubt the owner of X will agree to it.

**So, should I abandon my project Y, to make great improvements on X and basically take X into my own hands?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contributing to a project looks amazing on a resume, and coming in to make amazing improvements on projects also looks great. I'd say go for it.

I understand the feeling of wanting it to be yours however. I wouldn't stress about it, i mean you have your original code, you have communications (i assume) with the original owner. Heck it can be a great story to tell when a potential employer asks you about projects you've worked on in past (they will do this)

Answer (score 6):

If an abandoned project already does much of what you would do, and has a license you agree with, you can continue it if the original maintainers still respond, or fork it. In either case, you'll end up being a maintainer of it (including the parts you potentially don't care about or dislike).

Basically it's the balance between having a head-start plus a larger mindshare and not having a burden of some legacy code / design.

Also, great contributions to a great (if currently inactive) project would look *to me* better in a resume than a personal project which is 90% reinventing a wheel. If your project invents a significantly different and superior wheel, it could look good, though.